# Powershell to Add O365 User to a Mailbox with Send As Permission & Add them to Security Group with Full Access

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, permissions, powershell

Trying to come up with a way to add users with send as right to a mailbox and also add them with full control rights to a security group. At the moment I'm doing it with the below command...

```
$User = "UserEmail"
$Mailbox = "MailboxEmail"
$MailboxAccess = "SecurityGroup"
Add-RecipientPermission -Identity $Mailbox -AccessRights SendAs -Trustee $User -Confirm:$false
Add-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $MailboxAccess -Member $User -Confirm:$false -BypassSecurityGroupManagerCheck
```

But know this isn't the fastest way because I have to manually find the mailbox emails from O365 Admin Portal. Was trying something like the below...

```
$User = "UserEmail"
$Mailbox = Get-Mailbox -RecipientTypeDetails SharedMailbox -Anr *MailboxName* | Select-Object PrimarySmtpAddress
$MailboxAccess = Get-Group -Anr *SecurityGroupName* | Select-Object WindowsEmailAddress
Add-RecipientPermission -Identity $Mailbox -AccessRights SendAs -Trustee $User -Confirm:$True
Add-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $MailboxAccess -Member $User -Confirm:$True -BypassSecurityGroupManagerCheck
```

But that's failing because the cmdlets don't support piping. Pretty new to Powershell so any help/advice would be much appreciated.

*Edit*

Error message received when running is...

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> Add-RecipientPermission -Identity
 $Mailbox -AccessRights SendAs -Trustee $User -Confirm:$True
Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Identity'. Cannot convert
value "@{PrimarySmtpAddress=*EmailAddress*}" to type
"Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.RecipientIdParameter". Error: "Cannot
convert hashtable to an object of the following type:
Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.RecipientIdParameter.
Hashtable-to-Object conversion is not supported in restricted language mode or
a Data section."
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Add-RecipientPermission], Para
   meterBindin...mationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,Add-Recipie
   ntPermission
    + PSComputerName        : outlook.office365.com
```

Also tried running it without the additional Select-Objects at the end and still get similar...

```
    PS C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> Add-RecipientPermission -Identity  
 $Mailbox -AccessRights SendAs -Trustee $User -Confirm:$True  
Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Identity'. Cannot convert  
value "*EmailDisplayName*" to type  
"Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.RecipientIdParameter". Error: "Cannot  
convert hashtable to an object of the following type:  
Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.RecipientIdParameter.  
Hashtable-to-Object conversion is not supported in restricted language mode or  
a Data section."  
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Add-RecipientPermission], Para  
   meterBindin...mationException  
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,Add-Recipie  
   ntPermission  
    + PSComputerName        : outlook.office365.com
```

Comment: Where does the second script fail? Could you please [edit] your question to include the error message you get? Thanks!

Comment: Yeah no problem, that's been added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the example shown in [the TechNet page on `Add-RecipientPermission`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff935839), it appears that you can supply a simple string value for the `-Identity` parameter; it doesn't need a fancy object. The article also states (in the table of parameters) that you can use *any* name that uniquely identifies the principal, even the display name. The same goes for [`Add-DistributionGroupMember`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124340(v=exchg.160).aspx).

Therefore, you don't have to use `Get-Mailbox` or `Get-Group` to find the e-mail address of the recipient; you can just use your first script and supply the human-readable name.

If you do want to use those cmdlets, though, you need to get the plain e-mail address out of the one-property object returned by `select`. For example, you would supply `$MailboxAccess.WindowsEmailAddress` instead of just `$MailboxAccess`. You might even have to call `ToString()` on that value if it's yet another .NET object that doesn't automatically convert to something usable.

Comment: That worked a treat, cheers Ben! Used the second $MailboxAccess.WindowsEmailAddress option because when people are requesting these they don't always know the exact name so it's handy being able to use -Anr to search.